# Babel compile error: not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: javascript, html, babeljs

**Hello everyone**, I'm having trouble trying to compile a code due to babel.

> Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only
>   functions.

The error occurs in *babel-preset-react\lib\index.js*

I have done several searches and made several changes in the package.json however the error simply persists. I also created and configured a ".babelrc" file in the project root, though I do not know if I did it correctly.

*package.json*

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": ">=6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": ">=1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-private-properties": ">=1.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.8.3",
    "babelify": ">=7.3.0",
    "grunt": ">=1.0.1",
    "grunt-browserify": ">=5.0.0",
    "grunt-chokidar": ">=1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": ">=1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": ">=1.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": ">=1.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": ">=1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": ">=2.3.0",
    "grunt-tinyimg": ">=1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "autobind-decorator": ">=1.4.0",
    "gsap": ">=1.19.1",
    "jquery": ">=3.2.1",
    "jquery-mask-plugin": "^1.14.10",
    "pipwerks-scorm-api-wrapper": ">=0.1.2",
    "react": ">=15.5.4",
    "react-dom": ">=15.5.4",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\gem install compass susy breakpoint --source http://rubygems.org"
  }
}
```

and the .babelrc that i created

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/react", "@babel/es2015"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
      ]
}
```

If anyone could help, I would be very grateful. **Thank you all.**

Comment: Hi, I guess there is just a problem with the plugin itself...have you tried to update your modules ?

Comment: Hi, 
if you're talking about npm modules, I just ran the test and it did not work, anyway I do not think it's related to that because I have other applications with babel that compile normally, thx anyway